# dc.js boxplot b.map(...).sort is not a function

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, reductio

I am trying to generate box plot. After creating dimension and group I've followed the example given at 
https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/box-plot.html

I'm using [reductio](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio) to make the reductions easier:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(ds);
var skuDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.sku; });
var skuGroup = skuDim.group();

var reducer = reductio();
reducer
  .value('_nc')
  .sum(function(d){
      return d.nc;
  });
reducer
  .value('_ta')
  .sum(function(d){
      return d.ta;
  });

reducer(skuGroup);
```

I'm also using a valueAccessor for my group:

```
  .valueAccessor(function(p){
    return p.value._nc.sum ? Math.round(p.value._ta.sum / p.value._nc.sum * 100) / 100 : 0;
  })
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: b.map(...).sort is not a function.
```

I've added a fiddle to replicate this issue. https://jsfiddle.net/momhzyxp/7/

Cheers

Comment: The boxplot expects each value to be an array - it looks like you have already aggregated the data in your example. Instead, you need to supply the actual values (as is done in the example you linked). I am not sure of the reductio way to do this, but I've added the tag and hopefully @EthanJewett will drop by - looks like it may be [valueList](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-reductio-value-list) or [dataList](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-reductio-data-list).

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. Passing an array of values. It works now. Can't get reductio to work though :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using reductio to aggregate the values into sums, you can use [reductio.dataList](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-reductio-data-list) to produce arrays of the original rows that fall into each bin:

```
var reducer = reductio();
reducer
  .value('_rows')
  .dataList(true);

reducer(skuGroup);
```

Then, assuming you want to divide *each* `ta` by *each* `nc` (not sure what you are trying to do here), the `valueAccessor` looks like:

```
  .valueAccessor(function(p){
    var values = p.value._rows.dataList.map(function(v, i) {
      return v.nc ? Math.round(v.ta / v.nc * 100) / 100 : 0;
    });
    return values;
  })
```

(or you can do whatever you like with each `v.ta` and `v.nc`).

Fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oawbzdgy/11/

Comment: That's it! Thanks @Gordon.